# Answering with just a doc link

Tags: discussion, support, documentation

With the introduction of docs, how should we be expected to incorporate them into our answers?

For many questions I've seen, they can be answered by simply providing a link to the relevant doc. However, just leaving a link is not really a proper answer (even if it is a SO link).

My question is, what else should be provided?

My gut reaction is to treat the docs link as we do normal links and give context and maybe even our own custom example, does anyone have another opinion?